# Laravel 5 add profile/change page to basic authentication

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

Laravel 5 is bundled with a basic registering and authentication system which lacks some functionality needed for a real world situation (confirmation by email, profile page where the user can edit their data).

I would like to add this to the existing authentication system in Laravel 5. What are the right steps to take? Can I do it without altering the vendor files?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel isn’t supposed to be a working application out of the box. It gives you the very basics of user authentication in login and register. Any thing else, is up to you to implement.

You don’t need to alter the vendor files (and you should never do that). Laravel has an Auth controller, that uses a trait to provide the login and register methods. You can add your own methods to this controller.

In terms of how to implement the specifics of email verification, Laracasts produced a video on this very topic just recently: https://laracasts.com/lessons/email-verification-in-laravel

Profile pages, again, you’re going to have to do it yourself. All you need to do is create a controller with one action for displaying the edit profile form, and another action for saving the profile data for the currently logged-in user. This is not difficult.

Comment: Not helpful, not a real answer (kind way of saying rtfm). I know Laravel is a framework and not a working application. I don't need working code, just some directions.

Comment: @Klaaz I’m not sure what you’re wanting. Someone to give you the code? Someone to lead you by the hand? The functionality just doesn’t exist in a fresh Laravel install, so write it yourself. I’m not sure why you deemed this worthy of a down-vote.